# Gravatars in chat widgets turn into oversized identicons when not loaded properly

Tags: bug, chat-ads

I was refreshing a question, then a chat widget appeared in the sidebar at random. In it, I noticed that one particular gravatar was showing up oversized:

[image]

This particular user, I notice, actually has a Gravatar; it seems the image somehow failed to load and is being replaced with an identicon, and this identicon isn't showing up in the correct size. Needless to say, I haven't been able to reproduce it. What's up with that?

Comment: Oh noes, they're [escaping in new places now](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/121437/a-gravatar-has-escaped)!

Comment: _......déjà vu_

Comment: I reported this on Ask Ubuntu's meta some months ago, see http://meta.askubuntu.com/q/2086/19490.