# Giant gravatar on the right panel on Stack Overflow's homepage

Tags: bug, gravatar, facebook

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Gravatars in chat widgets turn into oversized identicons when not loaded properly](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/128156/gravatars-in-chat-widgets-turn-into-oversized-identicons-when-not-loaded-properl)

I suspect a bug on home page of Stack Overflow. User Radovan is using Facebook's profile picture

http://profile.ak.fbcdn.net/hprofile-ak-ash2/573803_572383379_1104597715_n.jpg

but as visible from the HTML, you'll see that Stack Overflow tries to get his gravatar.

```
<img title="Radoslav: 23 mins ago" src="http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/!http://graph.facebook.com/572383379/picture?type=large?s=23&amp;d=identicon&amp;r=PG">
```

[image]

Comment: Related FB boomboom: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126828/combined-stack-exchange-flair-makes-me-look-creepy

Comment: I reported this on Ask Ubuntu's meta some months ago, see http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/2086/one-users-picture-is-bigger-than-other-pictures-in-the-panel-showing-ubuntu-rel.