# Chat ads incorrectly expect users to have gravatar images

Tags: bug, status-completed, chat, chat-ads

The chat ads that are shown in the side bar of site pages incorrectly expect the user to always have a gravatar-based profile image:

```
var e = "http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/" + b.emailhash + "?s=23&d=identicon&r=PG"
```

This is incorrect behaviour for users who have Facebook or direct-upload profile images. As [Szabolcs points out in chat](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1245221#1245221), this is a particular problem for Facebook images which have their own query string, as it breaks the size argument to gravatar:

[image: oversized broken gravatar]

The JavaScript should check if the provided user `emailhash` value is a URL, and use that in place of the constructed gravatar URL when appropriate.

For the related issue of [the icon being allowed to be too large](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/128156/gravatars-in-chat-widgets-turn-into-oversized-identicons-when-not-loaded-properl), the generated `<img>` tag should be constrained to `height="23" width="23"` just in case.

Comment: I don't disagree, but what do you mean check if the emailhash is a URL? Your `var e` shows the url for the image, where `b.emailhash` is the unique id (hashed email) for the user, `s=23` is asking for a 23 pixel image and `d=identicon` is what specifies the default image if no img exists (like in this case). They could choose to return a 404 in the case of no img (and do something else)... but apparently aren't.

Comment: `b.emailhash` is an actual URL to the non-gravatar profile image in the above-mentioned cases, so you end up with `http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/http://i.stack.imgur.com/ljxup.png?s=23&d=identicon&r=PG`.

Comment: OK that makes total sense... I've only worked with the actual hashed email for generating gravatar URLs. Wasn't aware of what b.emailhash came out as... seems like a misnomer.

Comment: @Richard only 50 points? The devs will just laugh at your face! ;)

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd I clicked too fast and didnt bother to change it. It they don't fix it before the bounty period is up ill re bounty for 200

Comment: @Richard noble of you, but please let me. I have lots and honestly have no use of it over 20K... :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The direct-upload images will be handled correctly after the next build; the Facebook images will be handled *almost* correctly – we continue to make the assumption that avatars are square (this is guaranteed for gravatars and direct-upload avatars); for the rare case that a user has a non-square Facebook avatar, the image will appear stretched in the chat ad.