# Facebook imported picture is breaking the network profile design

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, network-profile, profile-picture

[This user](https://stackexchange.com/users/469035/cpilko) strikes [again](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/167267/152859). This time it's:

> [image]

Link to the original profile picture: http://profile.ak.fbcdn.net/hprofile-ak-snc6/273260_1427736689_310442525_n.jpg

I noticed it can be fixed by changing the image source from `http://graph.facebook.com/{id}/picture?type=large` to `http://graph.facebook.com/{id}/picture?type=normal`. (or enforce maximum width in the CSS itself)

Edit: now the image height is constrained to 128 pixels, so when the width is bigger than the height and both more than 128 pixels, it leads to something like this: ([profile link](https://stackexchange.com/users/9092/gms8994))

> [image]

Comment: strikes again? When did he strike before?

Comment: @hims056 see my edit. :)

Comment: I don't think it's Facebook causing it, I've seen super-large Gravatars as well.

Comment: @tombull89: most of those super large gravs are due to them being taken from FB. IIRC your avatar can be imported from FB as well, though I don't know the details. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/164058/chat-ads-incorrectly-expect-users-to-have-gravatar-images

Comment: The avatar is imported from Facebook if you used Facebook to log into the site for the first time. This issue of larger Facebook images [is recurring](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126828/combined-stack-exchange-flair-makes-me-look-creepy) and has appeared in a few avatar related issues.

Comment: @tombull89 for images hosted on gravatar or imgur they put querystring parameter to resize them to the desired size e.g. my pic is `http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/ab78492b42045cfabc0e857908519fea?s=128&d=identicon&r=PG` note the "?s=128". Even 10,000 pixels image will just be scaled down, server side.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The network profile's avatar is now constrained to 128px similarly to the rest of the network.

Comment: I saw its *height* is constrained (meaning the browser will scale the width) and there's no `overflow: hidden;` for its parent div, so for some pictures it still might break, no?

Comment: And I was right... see [this profile](http://stackexchange.com/users/9092/gms8994). (originally reported [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/198847/152859)).