# Profile picture is overflowing on network profile

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, profile-picture, network-profile

Have a look at [this user's network profile](https://stackexchange.com/users/9092/gms8994). The profile picture is overflowing.

> [image]

While his [Stack Overflow profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16645/gms8994) looks fine. Please fix this.

Comment: Facebook imported pictures are not resized like pictures hosted on imgur or Gravatar, hence this issue. Almost sure it was reported before, let me check...

Comment: I was the one to report it in the past, looks like the fix was overwritten at some point. :)

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd - Wow you also [reported him](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/167416/facebook-imported-picture-is-breaking-the-network-profile-design#comment-491481) that concern.

Comment: Yep, I feel like an oracle! ;)

Comment: I took the liberty to integrate your screenshot in my report, hope you don't mind! Also flagged my report asking to remove the [meta-tag:status-completed]. :)

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd - Nevermind :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`overflow: hidden;` added to the `user-avatar` CSS class.

Thank for reporting.

<s>With you in the next SE.com build.</s>

Done.

Comment: Doesn't it still look [wired](http://i.stack.imgur.com/ORjaF.png)? It's not a square.

Comment: @hims056 - You are right - there is some padding there, and the element is floated. Will see what I can do about it.

Comment: All we need is to remove right padding and add `margin-right: 15px;`

Comment: @hims056 - sorted.

Answer (score 4):

The reason is `<div class="user-avatar">` has `width: 128px;` and the image itself is 200px wide. So the text is not overflowing avatar's div, but image inside that div is too wide for it's container.

Stack Overflow uses `overflow: hidden;` on the avatar container div, so image is clipped and the right side of it is simply not visible. Network profile does not have this set.

Comment: But his Stack Overflow profile uses the same image. Probably we need to use the same class/style in network profile as Stack Overflow.

Comment: @hims056 updated.