# My profile picture changed, and I don't know how to change it back

Tags: support, login, gravatar

I have a profile picture on Stack Overflow, uploaded through Gravatar.

Yesterday, I changed my Stack Overflow login's e-mail, and the image disappeared.  When I clicked on the changed picture, it is going to the Gravatar page. But it still shows the old one, which I want to have set on Stack Overflow! I saved it again. But in Stack Overflow it was not changed. Now I have changed the Gravatar's email, which is the same with the Stack Overflow login's email, but the image on Stack Overflow is still the default-style profile image. It should be a winking cartoon brunette girl.

I don't know what's wrong. Did changing my logins break it?

Comment: Gravatar icons are heavily cached.  Try hitting Ctrl-F5 a few times.  I'm seeing a winking cartoon brunette girl, both here and on Stack Overflow.  Is that the old icon or the new one?

Comment: The downvotes are probably because of the readability of your post.  It's kind of difficult to tell what you were asking, probably because English is not your first language.  I've attempted to improve that aspect, hopefully I didn't change your meaning at all.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Weirdly, I've been stuck with a cached image for days before (specifically, here: [A Gravatar has escaped!](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/121437/a-gravatar-has-escaped)), and no amount of Ctrl+F5-ing fixed it.  Which makes me think it's some kind of server-side caching, but I'm not sure.

Comment: @jadarnel27 I can't remember definitively, but I do believe that there is some server side caching going on. Gravatar is awesome but _does_ tend to go down (not on a Twitteresque scale, but it does happen) which results in some broken looking pages. It's actually a _good_ idea to cache them to avoid that if Gravatar is the only option you provide to people.

Comment: @TimPost I've been pondering the rationale since I typed that comment.  Thanks for the insight, it would definitely make sense to force caching for the sake of improved general stability.

Comment: @jadarnel27 thanks for the improve ,English is not my first,and I still couldn't see the image I want to see now ,has been two hours after i asked the question.are there lots of wrong in my grammar this post?

Comment: @jadarnel27, see [Why isn't my Gravatar image updating?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21793/why-isnt-my-gravatar-image-updating/139803#139803)

Comment: So, Winnie, any answer to @Robert's question?

Comment: It [looks just fine to me](http://i.stack.imgur.com/LI1qs.png) - so likely browser cache on your side.

Comment: @Arjan I'm sorry ,I'm not understand "any answer to Robert's question".

Comment: Like Robert wrote: we're *seeing a winking cartoon brunette girl, both here and on Stack Overflow. Is that the old icon or the new one?*

Comment: @Arjan you both can see the pictures I upload.but till now I can only see the default-style profile image.this is fun.

Comment: @Arjan why do you like comment instead of answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have seen my profile images now ,There maybe two reasons:

1. Gravatar icons are heavily cached, so it needs time to show my change
2. I changed the Gravatar's email to the same e-mail in StackOverflow.

So I suggest whoever meets the same problem in the future to wait for 24 hours and see.

Comment: thanks ,i can see it now