# What if my question was solved in comments without an answer?

Tags: support

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Should old questions with a solution in the comments but no posted answer be answered?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139075/should-old-questions-with-a-solution-in-the-comments-but-no-posted-answer-be-ans)

My question was solved but no answer was given, so I don't know what to do... Should I answer the quesion myself with: "I have solve the problem" to avoid others to scan and answer it?

This is my question:

[My profile picture changed, and I don't know how to change it back](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/144550/my-profile-picture-changed-and-i-dont-know-how-to-change-it-back)

Comment: @Waffelized Bobby,I' m not duplicate this question.my question has solved ,I don't know to end it.and there is still person vote on it ~

Comment: I feel this will be another question without answers ~

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If someone solves your question in the comments, you can ask that user to post the solution in an answer and accept it.

If the user doesn't answer you or you see they are not going to do it, answer the question yourself, but [make it Community Wiki](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/privileges/community-wiki) and give attribution to the comment.