# Profile image in response tab not properly scaled in mobile view

Tags: bug, status-completed, mobile-web, gravatar

When viewing the responses tab on my profile in mobile view, one of the profile icons is threatening to take over my whole screen:

[image: rawr]

That shouldn't happen, should it?

I get the same result if I use Firefox and click on the *mobile* link in the footer.

The only difference with that [user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/679227/haralan-dobrev) is that when his profile image appears to be [hosted by facebook](http://profile.ak.fbcdn.net/hprofile-ak-ash4/369477_1800933170_850665_n.jpg) rather than gravatar.

Comment: Is that a disguise beard?

Comment: Not a dupe, but I think the same problem happened [this post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126828/combined-stack-exchange-flair-makes-me-look-creepy). It's a Facebook profile pic set to `type=large`.

Comment: @Asad An attempt at disguise, it is.

Comment: @Lix Yup, it does look like a similar bug hiding in a different corner.

Comment: [According to balpha](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/122905), Facebook images are supposed to be restricted via CSS, since they don't know the exact dimensions.

Comment: Perhaps some of the incantation to tame images from book of faces is missing from the mobile CSS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will be fixed in the next deploy.

Comment: Many thanks. I can confirm that the avatars are now behaving themselves.