# All mods are equal, but some mods are more equal

Tags: bug, status-completed, moderators, stackexchange.com, profile-picture

All mods are equal, right? Except for Kiamlaluno. Real funny...

[image]

[Bug found here.](https://stackexchange.com/about/moderators?by=users) I'm using Chrome 24.0.1312.52

Comment: Nice one! Kudos for noticing such a thing.. ;)

Comment: Reproed on Chrome 22.0.1229.79, Chromium 20.0.1132.47, Firefox 15.0.1 , and Lynx 2.8.8dev.9
on Ubuntu.

Comment: @Manishearth it's obviously in the code, the image is http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/f5ef1b81e1aeb3b921a3034d460ce6af?s=128&d=identicon&r=PG as you see there is explicit "?s=128" while for all the rest it's "?s=16".

Comment: So the Dev team likes Kiam 8 times better than the rest of us...

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd: I know, just felt like reproing it :P Which is why I did Lynx as well ;-) Can't see the image, but the URL clearly points to the 128 img

Comment: @Luke 8² times better.

Comment: I feel so unloved...

Comment: Ah, this kind of reminds me of the time *I* observed a [Gravatar escaping from its natural boundaries](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/121437/a-gravatar-has-escaped).

Comment: Reproduced on Safari 6.0.2. Add that to Manishearth's comment and it looks like this is broken across the board :o

Comment: PS: I love the literary reference in the title.

Comment: Also broken in IE 9

Comment: This is a big not a bug.

Comment: Now I got what you mean before with your chat message. `:)` I just noticed this post.

Comment: Now I feel special. It must be as Andy Warrol said: Everybody has a day to be famous. `;)`

Comment: @kiamlaluno enjoy it while it lasts! (although size doesn't matter :))

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This was a side-effect of changes made to the API to support the new custom profile image options.

It will be fixed in the next deploy.